# Angular won't load styles.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm building a simple `angular` app with `bootstrap`. It seems that the base `index.html` won't load the `styles.css`. If I put the css code right into html tags it works like a charm. I tried to reboot the app and clear the browser cache, it seems to just ignore the style file. When I wrote the css file for the first time it worked, hence I thought that was a cache problem. I changed nothing of the Angular project base structure.
Here's my code.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ReagApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}

.container{
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Here's the version that works instead.
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ReagApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body style="  background-color: #d9d9d9;">
  <div class="container"
      style="width: 70%;
      max-width: 100%;
        background-color: white;
        margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**.angular-cli.json**

```
[other things]
    "prefix": "app",
          "styles": [
            "styles.css",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
          ],
          "scripts": [
            "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
            "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
          ],
          "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
[other things]
```

The code is pretty trivial but still.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using to build your app? angular-cli?

Comment: if you are using angular CLI, you have to mention the path in styles array under .angular-cli.json.

Comment: I did that, I will update the question with the content of .angular-cli.json

Comment: Where in your folder structure is your styles.css?

Comment: @DeborahK in the same folder of index.html, src/app.

Answer (score 5):

Check your `angular-cli.json`, under `"apps"` you should see something like this

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

add it if its not there

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference your stylesheet in yout .angular-cli.json like this :

```
"styles": [
"path/to/style.css"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in your index.html, I don't see any `<link>` to that file... are you sure you didn't leave it out? You still need to link the stylesheet, Angular won't do that automatically for you.

Try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ReagApp</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <app-root></app-root>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: (-1 for the answer): Angular does it automatically if you are using angular-cli. You just have to specify the styles file path in the angular-cli.json